# perl regular expression using repetition/quantifier

Tags: regex, perl

Simple, I am trying to see if a field has 9 digits and nothing else.

my $var = 123456789

`( my $nine ) = ( $var =~ /\d{9}/ );`

from my understanding this says, "match a digit 9 times and nothing else"

this outputs `1` but not the `123456789` that i was expecting. Why?

Comment: The statement that you show "outputs" nothing. Do you expect `$nine` to contain `123456789`? What do you want in the case that `$var` is set to `'abcdef9873239998782116tyra'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing coming back in list context within the regex,
so the default is that it sets your variable `$nine` to the scalar result
of the regex function call. And that function call returns in scalar context
the number of matches.

If you were to change that to `(my $nine) = ($var =~ /\d/g);`
$nine would contain 9.

Add a capture buffer around the digits.

ie:

```
( my $nine ) = ( $var =~ /(\d{9})/ );
```

However, even though your syntax for your assignment will work,
its conventional to write it as

```
my ($nine) = $var =~ /(\d{9})/;
```

Comment: I am the idiot who downvoted your answer. You are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern matches a sequence of nine (international) digit character *anywhere* in the string. The `1` you are seeing is a *true* value that the pattern match returns to say that the match was successful.

If you just want to *verify* that the contents of a variable are *exactly* nine ASCII digits, then you should write

```
if ( $var =~ /\A[0-9]{9}\z/ ) { ... }
```

or, if you have the ASCII `/a` modifier available (any version of Perl 5 since 14) then you can say

```
if ( $var =~ /\A\d{9}\z/a ) { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

You really want this:

```
( my $nine ) = ( $var =~ /(\d{9})/ );
```

The problem is that `=~` is a comparison operator, and the result of the expression `( $var =~ /\d{9}/ )` is true (1).  Adding the parentheses in my example makes the regex capture its matches, so it returns your 123456789.

Comment: Care to educate me on what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: The OP asked to check *"if a field has 9 digits and nothing else"*. Your solution captures the first nine digit characters that it finds, or sets `$nine` to `undef` if there is no such subsequence.

Comment: @Borodin - The OP clearly states the problem is the assignment is `1`. He can find exactly 9 digits anywhere, can't he?

Comment: @sln: If you can derive that from *"I am trying to see if a field has 9 digits and nothing else"* then please explain. If `$var` contained `999999999` then `$nine` would still be set to `1`.

Comment: @Borodin - My take, he is using a test string with exactly 9 digits and nothing else trying to find out why he is getting 1 in the assignment.